# How do I solve the error in the Entity model definition?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Like I want to use List <> in the properties of the following entity models, the database does not accept it. How can I add a list type to the database as a column?

```
public class User: IdentityUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Education Education { get; set; }
}

public class Education
{
   public List<Graduation> Graduations { get; set; }
   public List<string> Graduated_schools { get; set; }  
}

public enum Graduation
{
    High_school=1,
    Middle_School=2,
    Primary_school=3,
}
```

Note: I defined the list as the user can graduate from several different high schools and secondary schools.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46677113/entity-framework-saving-a-collection-of-enums see following

Answer (score 0):

You need different relations in my opinion. `User` should have a many `Education`'s (needs additional work on naming).

```
public class User: IdentityUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Education> Educations { get; set; }
}

public class Education
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public Graduation GraduationLevel { get; set; }
   public string SchoolName { get; set; }
}
    
public enum Graduation
{
    High_school=1,
    Middle_School=2,
    Primary_school=3,
}
```

Comment: ICollaction is also not a type in the database

Comment: @SerkanSayer but you use Entity Framework Core, and it will map ICollection to relation one to many. First you need migrate database. Do you use code first or database first approach?

Comment: Did you generate migration and apply database update?

Comment: When I try to update the database, I get the following error.
table "Products" already exists'

Comment: So you have a different issue. Did you create all tables using EF or maybe you put tables manually? - it's different issue, maybe for new question.

Comment: I created the tables using ef.